# how to make bc to show me 10 and not 10.00

Tags: bc

```
#!/bin/bash 
q=$(bc <<< "scale=2;$p*100")
head -n$q numbers.txt > secondcoordinate.txt
```

That's just part of the script, but I think it's enough to clarify my intentions. `p` is a variable with just two decimals, so `q` should be an integer... Nevertheless,  `bc` shows, for example, `10.00` instead of `10`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: delete `scale=2;`

Comment: @Ipor Sircer  still doesn't work

Comment: Did you try scale=0?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, I did, but still shows two decimals

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do this with the obvious `scale=0` because of the way that the scale is determined.

The documentation indirectly explains that dividing by one is sufficient to reset the output to match the value of `scale`, which defaults to zero:

> **expr1 / expr2** The result of the expression is the quotient of the two expressions. The scale of the result is the value of the variable scale.

```
p=12.34; echo "($p*100)" | bc
1234.00

p=12.34; echo "($p*100)/1" | bc
1234
```

If your version of `bc` does not handle this, pipe it through `sed` instead:

```
p=12.34; echo "($p*100)" | bc | sed -E -e 's!(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0*$!\1!' -e 's!(\.0*)$!!'
1234
```

This pair of REs will strip trailing zeros from the decimal part of a number. So 3.00 will reduce to 3, and 3.10 will reduce to 3.1, but 300 will remain unchanged.

Alternatively, use `perl` and dispense with `bc` in the first place:

```
p=12.34; perl -e '$p = shift; print $p * 100, "\n"' "$p"
```

Comment: Perhaps using `printf` would be cleaner than piping through sed? e.g. `printf '%.0f\n' $(bc <<< "$p*100")`

Comment: @steeldriver that requires `printf` to interpret the string as a number and then reformat it. I'd have preferred to use the PCRE `(\.[0-9]?*)0*$` (which would strip trailing zeros from values such as 12.3400) but `sed` can't handle that.

Answer (score 5):

you can use awk to calculate the values

```
bash-3.2$ p=0.01
bash-3.2$ q=$(awk -vp_val="$p" 'BEGIN{print p_val*100}')
bash-3.2$ echo $q
1


bash-3.2$ p=0.02
bash-3.2$ q=$(awk -vp_val="$p" 'BEGIN{print p_val*100}')
bash-3.2$ echo $q
2


bash-3.2$ p=0.022
bash-3.2$ q=$(awk -vp_val="$p" 'BEGIN{print p_val*100}')
bash-3.2$ echo $q
2.2
```

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR

You have lots of options. *bc* has known behavior where `scale=0` doesn't always do what you expect, but there are a lot of workarounds. Here are just a few.

### printf

Use *printf* to limit your output to integers.

```
$ printf "%g\n" $(echo '12.34 * 100' | bc)
1234
```

### bc with division

If you want to stick with *bc* scaling, you need to specify both a scale of zero *and* divide by 1 to reset the scale. This is known behavior, but I really can't explain the why of it.

```
$ echo '12.34 * 100 / 1' | scale=0 bc
1234
```

### sed

Just strip off the unwanted trailing characters.

```
$ echo '12.34 * 100' | bc | sed 's/\.00$//'
1234
```

### bash

Use a brace expansion to return the value before the decimal.

```
$ p='12.34'; q=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $p*100"); echo ${q%%.00}
1234
```

Comment: Just one niggle - `${q%%.00}` would usually be referred to as *parameter expansion* rather than "brace expansion", I think

Comment: Using `scale=0 bc` sets the envvar `scale` which *bc* doesn't seem to read. It has to be included within the text piped to stdin.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem and wrote these 2 simple one-liners to clean the output:

```
define int(x) { auto z; z = scale; scale = 0; x /= 1; scale = z; return x; }
define n(x) { auto z, m, s;z = scale; m = x; while (int(m) != m) { m *= 10; s += 1; }; scale = s; x /= 1; scale = z; return x; }
```

Here `int(x)` turns a real number into an integer. It sets the scale to `0` and it divides the operand by `1` so the fractional part is cut off. `n(x)` will multiply the real number by `10` in a loop until the real number becomes an integer, i.e. all its fractional digits shifted to the left. `s` will match the number of fractional digits. So setting the `scale` to `s` and divide it by `1` will cut off the zeroes.

I've included these lines in a small `lib.bc` file containing all kinds of handy `bc` functions. Add the file as a parameter to bc to make these functions available (or, like myself, make an alias so every time you run `bc` you have them available)

You can use it like this:

```bash
echo "scale=20;2^-8"|bc lib.bc     # .00390625000000000000
echo "scale=20;n(2^-8)"|bc lib.bc  # .00390625
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bash function to remove trailing zeroes.

```bsh
remove_trailing_zeroes()
{
    declare -n n="$1"
    # Prepend a 0 if number starts with a dot.
    if [[ $n =~ ^[.] ]]; then
        n="0$n"
    fi
    # Remove trailing zeroes
    while [[ $n =~ [.].*0$ ]]; do
        n="${n%0}"
    done
    # Remove trailing dot if any
    if [[ $n =~ [.]$ ]]; then
        n="${n%.}"
    fi
}
```

You can then use it like this for your case:

```bsh
q=$(bc <<< "scale=2;$p*100")
remove_trailing_zeroes q
head -n$q numbers.txt > secondcoordinate.txt
```

Comment: le sigh.  This may work but it is a terrible approach to ops problem...and likely overkill for any problem.

Comment: @Jesse_b: I just copied a function I had created and used myself to solve a similar but more general problem. I don't see why you say it's a terrible or overkill approach.